# Close Excel Application if Word crashes while reading from Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to ensure that an Excel file is not left open if a Word application that is gathering data from it via a macro suddenly crashes.

The macro handles most errors using the code below, but I want to ensure that the Excel file isn't left hanging open in the face of an unhandled event. Such an event might be the user closing the word document from the task manager while the macro is running.

```
Public Function GatherDataFromExcel(x) As Collection

    On Error GoTo CloseExcel

    Dim path_file_excel As String
    path_file_excel = "\path to file\file.xlsx"

    Dim objXL As Object ' Excel.Application
    Dim objBook As Object ' Excel.Workbook

    Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    On Error Resume Next

    Set objBook = objXL.Workbooks.Open(path_file_excel)
    On Error Resume Next

    'Code that gathers data and returns that data from the function

CloseExcel:

    If Not objBook Is Nothing Then
        objBook.ActiveWorkbook.Close
        objBook.Close
        Set objBook = Nothing
        If Not objXL Is Nothing Then
            Set objXL = Nothing
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

I have closed the word document mid execution to check, and indeed the excel file is left hanging open. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Have you tried removing `On Error Resume Next` to see if you're getting an error? You never return to `On Error GoTo CloseExcel` either.

Comment: If someone kills Word from task manager then I think you’re stuck. You’d need to use another method that doesn’t open Excel in its own exclusive process. That’s my thinking anyway.

Comment: If Word *crashes*, you're not going to get any chance at error handling or cleanup, any more than you get a chance to tidy your car for the paramedics before a drunk driver crosses over into your lane and hits your car. A *crash* is a *crash*, not something you can plan to handle, especially when the app that would be handling it is the one that is crashing.

Comment: Thanks dwirony. I do return to `On Error GoTo CloseExcel`, I just didn't show it in the code above. I go to it in case of other errors that may be encountered, but that aren't relevant for the purposes of this problem. I haven't tried removing `On Error Resume Next`. I'll try that now, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Skin and Ken White. Good analogy Ken White! I'm not sure how I'd do what you suggested Skin, 'use another method that doesn’t open Excel in its own exclusive process'. Can you provide guidance?

Comment: Pehaps one route to consider is to have an autostart macro in Excel that runs on a timer event.  The macro just checks if it can do a GetObject for the word application and if not then it closes the excel application.

Comment: @cohara actually, I had another idea. Is the issue because the workbook is then locked the next time you try to open it after a crash or is it merely a memory/clean up thing you want to make sure you do?

Comment: Hello Skin, its that I don't want the Excel to be locked for other users afterwards. It's just occurred to me that I should access the data as read only if possible, I'm going to look into that now, as well as look at Digiwise's suggestions below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Word crashes you are going to need a different process to close Excel.

A few options:

1. Show Excel to the user so that the user can close Excel `objXL.visible = true`
2. If your VBA error handler does run you probably want to change:

   ```
   objBook.ActiveWorkbook.Close
   objBook.Close
   ```

   To

   ```
   objBook.Close False ' Close workbook without saving changes
   objXL.Quit ' Exit Excel
   ```
3. As Freeflow suggested, have another process (e.g. timer event in Excel or a separate VBScript process) that closes Excel if it can't find the Word document

Comment: Thank you Digiwise. Leaving the Excel file open is a neat way of alerting the user to its presence. This should suffice for what I need.